# how to omit spaces in overleaf latex reference

Tags: latex, biblatex

I am using the below reference in .bib file overleaf project

```
@MISC{104,author = {W. R. Group},title = {Auckland II},howpublished = {https://wand.net.nz/wits/auck/2/auckland\_ii.php.}, year = {2020}, month = {Accessed on: July, 1}}
```

However, I get spaces in my references as shown in the link below
[reference output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBp69.png)

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- you shouldn't set urls as normal text. Use the `\url{...}` macro from the `hyperref` or `url` package instead
- Once you have done this, you can use the `xurl` package to provide more possible break points and thus avoid such spaces

Unrelated comment:

- the `month` field is not the right place to give additional information like `Accessed on: July, 1`. If you'd choose an appropriate entry type instead of `@misc` it would have its own field for this, e.g. `urldate`